# Does relative path within the debug info depends on compiler or makefile?

Tags: debugging, compiler-construction, makefile, relative-path

anyone knows the relative path within the debug info depends on compiler or makefile ?

i like relative info, because i can put my project everywhere;

but sometimes, debugger can't find source code due to the dismatching path.

I don't know who controls using relative path or absolute path in debug info, maybe the compiler, maybe makefile, and maybe both;

anyone knows exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little fuzzy around the edges, but...

With the compiler and debugger *I* use, the choice of relative or absolute is determined by the paths passed to the compiler. So if you want to change the behavior, you have to change the command which invokes the compiler, which means changing the command in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> anyone knows exactly?

You didn't provide sufficient details in your question to answer it *exactly*.

The `Makefile` defines the command your make will execute.

- If you execute `$(CC) -g -c foo.c -o foo.o`, then most compilers will
  encode relative path `foo.c` into the object file. Some compilers
  will also encode current compilation directory, so the debugger can
  find the original `foo.c` even after you've copied the binary
  somewhere else (`gcc` on Linux will do that, as would most other
  compilers that use `DWARF` debug info).
- On the other hand, if you `Makefile` executes `$(CC) -g -c /path/to/src-directory/foo.c -o /path/to/obj-dir/foo.o`, then most compilers will encode full path into the object file.